# increase counter but decrease with DELAY

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching, redis

I want to keep a counter to see how many users are calling web service. web service almost completes in a second. I can increase a variable at the beginning and decrease at the end but its not what I want.

I need to increment variable at the beginning and decrease the count AFTER 3 seconds. I considered to use cache expire but I'll have more than 1000 calls in a second and I don't want to put extra load on server or memory. Also I know fire and forget methods like (hangfire) can work but in that case I need to run timer in a class for every request.

Also this method must be thread safe. I use Redis recently so if there exists this kind of function it can be a solution for me. Also I prefer it.

currently what I do is:
write a record to db with creation date at the begining
after that delete records older than 2 second 
run the procedure

but this loads database and I could not come up with a easy solution.

any ideas please ?
thanks.

edit:
I made the below sample. keep pressing increment button and around 90.000 you'll get "Object variable not set" error in line :

```
Cache("x") = CInt(Cache("x").ToString) + 1
```

...

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Web.Hosting

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub cmdIncrement_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdIncrement.Click
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10000
            If Cache("x") Is Nothing Then Cache("x") = 0
            Cache("x") = CInt(Cache("x").ToString) + 1
            fireit()
        Next
        getvalue()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub cmdRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRefresh.Click
        getvalue()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        getvalue()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub getvalue()
        If Cache("x") Is Nothing Then Cache("x") = 0
        Label1.Text = Cache("x").ToString & " - " & Now.ToString
    End Sub
    Protected Sub fireit()
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Function(token) DecrementMyVariable("aaa", token))
    End Sub

    Protected Shared Async Function DecrementMyVariable(text As String, token As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
        Await Task.Delay(5000)
        Dim x As Integer = CInt(HttpRuntime.Cache("x").ToString)
        HttpRuntime.Cache("x") = x - 1
        Return "aaa"
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to store to a log the date and time of each call to the service. You can then plot this over a given time period. Save the details to a CSV file and you can just review the data in Excel.

You could store this to a database and then query the database to find all calls within the last three seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same thing in memory that you are currently doing in the database.  Create a shared `List(Of Date)` object.  Each time any method is called, add `Date.Now` to that list.  Then have a timer that fires every second which removes any items from that shared list that are older than your desired three-second threshold.  Any time you want to get the current number of users, you can just read that list's `Count` property.  Put `SyncLock` around all the places that you modify or access that list in order to make it thread-safe.